# Magento 2 : Display cross sell products in products details page only for out of stock products:

Tags: magento2, out-of-stock, cross-sells

How to display cross sell products on the products details page for the out of stock products only?

Comment: you want to show at product details page?

Comment: balu,please put  your question otherwise question is going to close

Comment: yes @AmitBera , i want  to show in pdp page

Answer (score 1):

Suppose, *you want to  add Crosssellsection at product detail page and want to show current product's Crosssellproducts*  then you need to create an extension.

On this extension,  you will ***need to create a block which give  you current product Crosssell products***.

> app/code/{VendorName}/{ModuleName}/Block/Crosssell.php

```
<?php
namespace {VendorName}\{ModuleName}\Block;

class Crosssell extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct
{
    /**
     * Crosssell item collection
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Link\Product\Collection
     */
    protected $_itemCollection;

    /**
     * Prepare crosssell items data
     *
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Crosssell
     */
    protected function _prepareData()
    {
        $product = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('product');
        /* @var $product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */

        $this->_itemCollection = $product->getCrossSellProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(
            $this->_catalogConfig->getProductAttributes()
        )->setPositionOrder()->addStoreFilter();

        $this->_itemCollection->load();

        foreach ($this->_itemCollection as $product) {
            $product->setDoNotUseCategoryId(true);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Before rendering html process
     * Prepare items collection
     *
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Crosssell
     */
    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        $this->_prepareData();
        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve crosssell items collection
     *
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Link\Product\Collection
     */
    public function getItems()
    {
        return $this->_itemCollection;
    }

    protected function _toHtml()
    {
            /* if product is out stock then render html  */
            if (!$this->_coreRegistry->registry('product')->isSaleable()) {
                return '';
            }
            return parent::_toHtml();
    }


}
```

Now, you need  create layout file `catalog_product_view.xml` at

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{mytheme}/{VendorName}/{ModuleName}/layout

**Now add below code at this layout files:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<referenceContainer name="content.aside">
    <block class="{VendorName}\{ModuleName}\Block\Product\ProductList\Crosssell" name="product.info.upsell" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">upsell</argument>
        </arguments>
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="crosssell.product.addto" as="addto">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                   name="upsell.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                   template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </block>
 </referenceContainer>    
 </page>
```